# How to fix npm throwing error without sudo

Tags: node.js, unix, permissions, npm, sudo

I just installed node and npm through the package on nodejs.org, and whenever I try to search or install something with npm, it throws the following error unless I sudo the command.  I have a feeling this is a permissions issue?  I am already the admin.

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/chietala/.npm/-/all/.cache.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/chietala/.npm/-/all/.cache.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/chietala/.npm/-/all/.cache.json' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "search" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/chietala
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! path /Users/chietala/.npm/-/all/.cache.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/chietala/.npm/-/all/.cache.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chietala/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Please consider [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24404451/1480391) using **NVM**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24404451/1480391 (instead of hacking with permissions)

Comment: @janaspage You can not install node or NVM (Node Version Manager) via [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/) (Node Package Manager), it's non sense. NPM comes within node (it is installed at the same time). Have a look at the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)

Comment: Finally a solution better than `sudo chown`: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Comment: Under OSX and installing node with the 0official pkg intaller this solution did not work. I used this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34968008/675565

Comment: It explains the issue and the fix: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: Watch out! Do not only chown or chmod the directory! See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41395398/1256697

Comment: If the platform you are using is unix then you can use npm install --unsafe-perm. Npm doc.: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm

Comment: Chad please change answer to good solution , not messing with permission as suther gave.

Comment: wow I haven't checked on this in over 10 years. Changed the accepted solution.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Watch OUT!!!** **Watch OUT!!!** **Watch OUT!!!**

chown or chmod is **NOT** the solution, because of security-risk.

**Instead do this, do:**

First check, where npm point to, if you call:

```bash
npm config get prefix
```

If /usr is returned, you can do the following:

```bash
mkdir ~/.npm-global
export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin
```

This create a npm-Directory in your Home-Directory and point `npm` to it.

To got this changes permanent, you have to add the export-command to your .bashrc:

```bash
echo -e "export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global\nexport PATH=\$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMO - avoids messing with system dir ownership. INstalling with sudo can also lead to rights issues further down the road (since stuff might end up ownded by root as well...)

Comment: So what to do about stuff already installed globally?  Especially if some of it is old and other stuff depends on that particular version?

Comment: Whenever I get hold of a new machine (either physical or virtual), this is amongst my list to to setup. Saw this last at least 4 years back, and it is still relevant. Surprisingly, it is not the Accepted answer yet

Answer (score 2489):

This looks like a permissions issue in your home directory. To reclaim ownership of the **.npm** directory execute:

```bash
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Comment: I thought that `whoami` was a placeholder, but it works typed literally as-is, so it must be a variable I don't understand.

Comment: whoami is an actual shell command http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami. The backticks around `whoami` ensure that it gets executed correctly and then placed into the chown command

Comment: This is good, but there's a more complete answer for npm newbies such as myself. Might need to create a new /npm dir & also point npm to use it. See suther's answer below.

Comment: Using the answer below `npm config get prefix` showed that I had to do this for `~/.nvm` as well.

Comment: Thanks! This command solved a lot of issues in Mac.

Answer (score 746):

Permissions you used when installing Node will be required when doing things like writing in your *npm directory* (`npm link`, `npm install -g`, etc.).

You probably ran Node.js installation with root permissions, that's why the global package installation is asking you to be root.

---

## Solution 1: NVM

> Don't hack with permissions, install Node.js the right way.

On a development machine, you should not install and run Node.js with root permissions, otherwise things like `npm link`, `npm install -g` will need the same permissions.

[NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version Manager) allows you to install Node.js without root permissions and also allows you to install many versions of Node to play easily with them.. Perfect for development.

1. Uninstall Node (root permission will probably be required). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9283472/1480391) might help you.
2. Then install [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) following instructions [on this page](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).
3. Install Node via NVM: `nvm install node`

Now `npm link`, `npm install -g` will no longer require you to be root.

Edit: See also https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

---

## Solution 2: Install packages globally for a given user

> Don't hack with permissions, install npm packages globally the right way.

If you are on OSX or Linux, you can **create a user dedicated directory for your global package** and setup `npm` and `node` to know how to find globally installed packages.

Check out [**this great article**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) for step by step instructions on installing npm modules globally without sudo.

See also: npm's documentation on [Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Comment: Of all the solutions posted the NVM solution here provided the best results for me. Highly recommend using NVM rather than toying with permissions.

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me.

Comment: I installed node from the snap store but I could not run commands like npm install -g. But after trying the NVM solution everything worked smoothly. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This article was helpful as well: https://medium.com/devops-techable/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-on-macos-with-homebrew-1bc10626181

Comment: **WARNING** Using only `npm install node` will install the latest (non-LTS) version! To install the LTS (safer) version, use `npm install --lts` instead.

Answer (score 399):

Also you will need the write permission in `node_modules` directory:

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I don't know why this still gets upvotes. It is a very bad practice to change the ownership of system directories to a particular user!
Please see answer below for other solutions (like creating a separate group for node users).

Comment: Whatever you do -- ABSOLUTELY do not run 'sudo chmod -R whoami' on /usr/local/lib or /usr/lib/ you will ruin your sudoers file and you will hate yourself.

Comment: i poked around changing permissions on node-only stuff until I got an error about not being able to install a *man page*... like holy ^%$# I can't change the permissions there as that affects a *lot* more than just node!

Answer (score 135):

Changing the owner on "system-global" folders is a hack. On a fresh install, I would [configure NPM to use an already writable location](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) for "user-global" programs:

```bash
npm config set prefix "${HOME}/npm"
```

Then make sure you add that folder to your path:

```bash
export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/npm/bin"
```

To avoid future issues, do not use <s>`sudo npm ...`</s> at all.

See [@ErikAndreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712034) to [NPM modules won't install globally without `sudo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo), and [longer step-by-step guide](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) by @sindresorhus with also sets `$MANPATH`.

Comment: Just to note the actual path for current versions of node should be `.npm` and `.npm/bin`

Comment: @ChrisRutherford: as you can see the path is configurable, so it can be any accessible path you want. Chose to _not_ use a dot-name in this answer/example, both because `~/.npm` would collide with the "broken" directory in the original question, and because using a hidden directory (at least by default on *nix systems) would be harder to debug when you "just want things to work" and get on with your day.

Answer (score 59):

I encountered this when installing Recess (https://github.com/twitter/recess) to compile my CSS for Bootstrap 3.

When installing recess:

```
-npm install recess -g
```

1. You need to unlock permissions in your `home` directory, like [Noah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095114/noah)
   says:

   ```
   sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
   ```
2. You also need write permissions to the `node_modules` directory, like [Xilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712832/xilo)
   says, so if it still isn't working, try:

   ```
   sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
   ```
3. If you are still seeing errors, you may also need to [correct `/usr/local` permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/are-my-permissions-for-usr-local-correct):

   ```
   sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
   ```

Please note that as indicated [in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/are-my-permissions-for-usr-local-correct) `/usr/local/` isn't actually a system dir if you are on a Mac, so, this answer is actually perfectly "safe" for Mac users. However, if you are on Linux, see [Christopher Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842302/christopher-will)'s answer below for a multi-user friendly, system dir safe (but more complex) solution.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You probably do not want system directories to be owned by a particular user. Beside serious security concerns this is also not multiuser compatible.

Comment: It terrifies me that this has so many upvotes. Changing ownership of `/usr/local` is permanent system damage by definition, and can only be undone with a full OS install. It is a MASSIVE security issue, and has the potential to make some systems unbootable. This answer is as good as being a virus. I'm sorry, but I have to flag this for deletion.

Answer (score 40):

Other answers are suggesting to change ownerships or permissions of system directories to a specific user. I highly disadvise from doing so, this can become very awkward and might mess up the entire system!

Here is a more generic and safer approach that supports multi-user as well.

Create a new group for node-users and add the required users to this group. Then set the ownership of node-dependant files/directories to this group.

```
# Create new group
sudo groupadd nodegrp 

# Add user to group (logname is a variable and gets replaced by the currently logged in user)
sudo usermod -a -G nodegrp `logname`

# Instant access to group without re-login
newgrp nodegrp

# Check group - nodegrp should be listed as well now
groups

# Change group of node_modules, node, npm to new group 
sudo chgrp -R nodegrp /usr/lib/node_modules/
sudo chgrp nodegrp /usr/bin/node
sudo chgrp nodegrp /usr/bin/npm

# (You may want to change a couple of more files (like grunt etc) in your /usr/bin/ directory.)
```

Now you can easily install your modules as user

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```

Some modules (grunt, bower, yo etc.) will still need to be installed as root. This is because they create symlinks in /user/bin/.

**Edit**

3 years later I'd recommend to use [Node Version  Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). It safes you a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: If node is installed by sources, although multiuser would be a problem, all modules would work perfectly without the use of sudo. This is also very important because in the case of the yeoman module, people can't update generators through sudoing the yeoman application as it doesn't allow sudo execution :(

Comment: On Linux, I typically use the built-in `staff` group to give permissions to my dev folders. Also, it's a good idea to run `chmod g+ws node_modules` to make sure that your group has read/write permission.

Answer (score 32):

The **official documentation** on how to fix `npm install` permissions with an `EACCES` error is located at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.

I encountered this problem after a fresh install of node using the `.pkg` installer on OSX. There are some great answers here, but I didn't see a link to npmjs.com yet.

**Option 1: Change the permission to npm's default directory**

1. Find the path to npm's directory:

   ```
   npm config get prefix
   ```

For many systems, this will be **/usr/local**.

**WARNING**: If the displayed path is just **/usr**, switch to *Option 2*.

2. Change the owner of npm's directories to the name of the current user (your username!):

   ```
   sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
   ```

   This changes the permissions of the sub-folders used by npm and some other tools (**lib/node_modules**, **bin**, and **share**).

**Option 2: Change npm's default directory to another directory**

There are times when you do not want to change ownership of the default directory that npm uses (i.e. **/usr**) as this could cause some problems, for example if you are sharing the system with other users.

Instead, you can configure npm to use a different directory altogether. In our case, this will be a hidden directory in our home folder.

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   ```
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
3. Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

   ```
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked for me as the chown soludion did not. You saved me.

Comment: I love this answer's option 2. (1) It doesn't have the security vulnerabilities of using sudo, (2) it preserves architecture for other users, (3) it references the documentation, AND (4) it has the needed command line entries included. Thank you for adding!

Comment: So what happens when you install something that's symlinked into `/usr/bin/`? Now only your user can access it. You log in as someone else, still no access, since the files are actually in another user's home directory!

Comment: Hi @hoppykamper - on step 3, how do you "create a profile file"? Thank you!

Comment: @econobro depends on your shell and OS. Sometimes you should use `.bashrc`, others `.bash_profile`, or `.profile`. Can't answer you what's your case. However, to create the file, simply type `touch ~/.profile`. (`~` correspond to your user's directory under `/home`).

Answer (score 20):

I ran into this issue, and while it's true that `~/.npm` should be owned by your user, `npm` was not installing the modules there.

What actually solved my issue is these commands:

```
npm config set prefix ~/.npm
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm/bin"
```

It will make sure that all your global installation will go under this prefix. And it's important that your user owns this directory.

Comment: I had to do the same thing on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This helped on WSL with Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me so much pain. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

As if we need more answers here, but anyway..

Sindre Sorus has a guide [Install npm packages globally without sudo on OS X and Linux](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) outlining how to cleanly install without messing with permissions:

> Here is a way to install packages globally for a given user.
>
> 1. Create a directory for your global packages
>
>    ```
>    mkdir "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
>    ```
> 2. Reference this directory for future usage in your .bashrc/.zshrc:
>
>    ```
>    NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"
>    ```
> 3. Indicate to npm where to store your globally installed package. In your `$HOME/.npmrc` file add:
>
>    ```
>    prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages
>    ```
> 4. Ensure node will find them. Add the following to your .bashrc/.zshrc:
>
>    ```
>    NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
>    ```
> 5. Ensure you'll find installed binaries and man pages. Add the following to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:
>
>    ```
>    PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
>    # Unset manpath so we can inherit from /etc/manpath via the `manpath`
>    # command
>    unset MANPATH # delete if you already modified MANPATH elsewhere in your config
>    MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"
>    ```
>
> Check out [npm-g_nosudo](https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo) for doing the above steps automagically

*Checkout the [source of this guide](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) for the latest updates.*

Comment: tx for the edit @AndyHayden :) My preferred method is suggested in comments above: use NVM! http://stackoverflow.com/a/24404451/1480391

Comment: The only solution that worked for me that doesn't involve mucking about with permissions. I hate NPM and its idiotic permissions stupidity. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR

> always use `sudo -i` or `sudo -H` when running `npm install` to install global packages.

---

When you use `npm`, it downloads packages to your user home directory.  When you run as sudo, `npm` installs files to the same directory, but now they are owned by root.

So this is what happens to absolutely every single person who has ever used `npm`:

- install some local packages without issue using `npm install foo`
- install global package using `sudo install -g foo-cli` without issue
- attempt to install local package with `npm install bar`
- get frustrated at the `npm` designers now that you have to go `chmod` a directory again

When you use the `-i` or `-H` option with sudo, your home directory will be `root`'s home directory.  Any global installs will cache packages to `/root/.npm` instead of `root`-owned files at `/home/me/.npm`.

Just always use `sudo -i` or `sudo -H` when running `npm install` to install global packages and your `npm` permissions problems will melt away.

For good.

--
*q.v.* the accepted answer for fixing an already messed up `npm`.

Comment: best and simple fix

Comment: FYI, Last link is seems to now be broken.

Answer (score 7):

When you run npm install -g somepackage, you may get an EACCES error asking you to run the command again as root/Administrator. It's a permissions issue.

It's **easy to fix**, open your terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal)

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

** I strongly recommend you to not use the package management with sudo (sudo npm -g install something), because you can get some issues later **

Reference: http://foohack.com/2010/08/intro-to-npm/

Comment: Yay! this one did it to me! after doing the other other ones above: `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` ~/.npm`,  `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local/lib` and

Comment: This can cause permissions problems with lots of other apps, so I'd suggest *not* doing this. Why trade one can of worms for another?

Comment: Or at least refine it to /usr/local/lib/node_modules.

Comment: This, this and more this. After banging my head against a wall, this did the trick. +1

Comment: This was my issue.  On a new macbook (os x 10.10.3), permissions on /usr/local/lib/node_modules were:  $ ll /usr/local/lib/node_modules
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 24561  wheel   102B Mar 31 18:19 .
drwxrwxr-x   4 24561  admin   136B Mar 31 18:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x  26 65534  staff   884B Apr 13 10:53 npm

Comment: Or sudo chown -R $USER ~/local/lib/node_modules depending on how node was installed.

Comment: Using `sudo` is fine, but you should use the `-H` option.  See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem at [NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo/19354387), the issue was that **when i installed node i did it with sudo via chris/lea ppa repo**.

My solution was to uninstall node and then install it this way:

Download latest stable node sources from nodejs.org #in my case node-v0.10.20.tar.gz

> tar -zxf node-v0.10.20.tar.gz #uncompress sources
>
> cd node-v0.10.20 #enter uncompressed folder
>
> sudo chown $USER -R /usr/local
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install

PD: If you don't want to change ownership of the /usr/local folder, you can install it somewhere you already own. The problem of this approach is that you will have to bind the installation folder with the bash command line so that we can use the node command later on

> mkdir ~/opt
>
> ./configure --prefix=~/opt && make && make install
>
> echo 'export PATH=~/opt/bin:${PATH}' >> ~/.bashrc #or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshenv depending on the current Operative System

With either of those approaches, you will be able to do the following without using sudo

> npm install -g module_to_install

Comment: I ended up using this method. Did use `sudo chown $USER /use/local` before building. Looks good so far, time to try to build atom! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For Mac (adopted from Christoper Will's answer)

Mac OS X 10.9.4

1. System Preference > Users & Groups > (unlock) > press + :

   New Account > "Group"
      Account Name : nodegrp

   After creating the group, tick the user to be included in this group
2. > sudo chgrp -R nodegrp /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
   >       sudo chgrp nodegrp /usr/bin/node
   >       sudo chgrp nodegrp /usr/bin/npm
   >       sudo chown -R $(whoami):nodegrp ~/.npm

Comment: I had to change a couple of the paths to /usr/local/bin but other than that this solution worked great on my OX X 10.9 machine - thanks !

Comment: Bad practice to change ownership of system directories.

Comment: @richremer I think it depends on what you trying to achieve. if the folder is originally only accessible by the sudoer then it can be only be changed in this way. we limit the change to the folder related to npm. Would it be more safe to keep do `sudo` or change those folder group ownership so that it can be modified by normal user? If normal user is not supposed to perform any action on this folder then of course should not change the group ownership of the folder.

Comment: The appropriate thing to do is install global packages with sudo, but do it with the `-H` flag.  Specifically, `sudo -H npm install -g <pkg>`.  This ensures proper delineation of permissions for system and user folders.  What you don't want to do is use `sudo npm install -g`, because this installs root-owned files to your user directory.  It would be great if npm were smart enough to do this the right way, but it's not, so you have to use the `-H` sudo flag to properly install globally.

Answer (score 5):

For me, execute only

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

doesn't work. Then, I execute too

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/lib/node_modules/
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/bin/node
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/bin/npm
```

And all works fine!

Comment: You are very awesome sir :)

Comment: Files in `/usr/lib` are system files and should not be owned by your personal user account.

Answer (score 5):

**ISSUE**: You (the user) don't have the right set of permissions for the directory.

The instant way out is to run the npm install using sudo, but this may give you the same error, or improper installation.

AND changing directory ownership is not a good option, a temporary patch.

---

**Solution**/**Suggestion**: Change npm's Default Directory (from official [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-two-change-npms-default-directory))

Back-up your computer before moving forward.

(optional) In case you have a erroneous installation, first uninstall it:

```
npm uninstall <package-name>  # use sudo if you used it while installation
npm cache verify  # or, npm cache clean for npm version below 5.x.x
```

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   **`mkdir ~/.npm-global`**
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   **`npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`**
3. Open or create a `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file and add this line:

   **`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`**
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables, or restart the terminal:

   **`source ~/.profile`**
5. (optional) Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

   **`npm install -g jshint`**

Answer (score 4):

In my case,it's because of the permission of ~/tmp.So I do:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/tmp
```

And it's OK!

Answer (score 4):

Problem:
You do not have permission to write to the directories that npm uses to store global packages and commands.

Solution:
Allow permission for npm.

Open a terminal:

> command + spacebar then type 'terminal'

Enter this command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

- Note: this will require your password.

This solution allows permission to ONLY the directories needed, keeping the other directories nice and safe.

Comment: Downvoting because setting user ownership of system folders is an anti-pattern and this does not account for that.  In the special case that `npm config get prefix` returns something in the home folder, this solution will fix the permissions, but doesn't address the underlying problem of installing global packages in a safe way for a shared environment.

Comment: This will rewrite the permissions of a huge portion of the operating system. Running this in Ubuntu for example will result in "sudo" command itself becoming unusable.

Comment: changing `sudo` permission is a big NO!!

Answer (score 2):

Another great fix here to configure NPM properly, run the following commands :

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm_packages'
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.npm_packages/bin; export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Best solution would be [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) which is provided by npm documentation.

---

For Ubuntu suggested solution is [Option#2](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory)

Brief steps:
Make a directory for global installations:
**`mkdir ~/.npm-global`**

Configure npm to use the new directory path:
**`npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`**
`npm config get prefix` can help you to verify if prefix was updated or not. The result would be <Your Home Directory>/.npm-global

Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
**`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`**

Back on the command line, update your system variables:
**`source ~/.profile`**

Instead of steps 2-4 you can also use the corresponding ENV variable
(e.g. if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):

`NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`

---

For Mac suggested solution is [Option#3](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-3-use-a-package-manager-that-takes-care-of-this-for-you)

On Mac OS you can avoid this problem altogether by using the Homebrew package manager

**`brew install node`**

Comment: This NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX won't work. 

This is an error in npm-descriptiton. See my post above, how to do it in the right way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41395398/1256697

Answer (score 2):

In case `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm` didn't work for you, or you need a non terminal command solution.

The issue is that your user account does not have write permission to node_modules folder, so you can do the following

1. Open finder and press `cmd` + `shift` + `g` this will open go to folder with url
2. Write the following path `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and press go
3. Right click on `node_modules` folder and choose `Get Info`
4. Scroll down to `sharing & permissions` section
5. Unlock to be able to make changes.
6. Press `+` and add your user account
7. Make sure that you choose `Read & Write` in privilege drop down

Now you should be able to install packages without `sudo` and permission issues should be solved

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned this, but there is actually no need to mess up with permissions or a separate npm installation, just specifying a different cache folder to the command will fix the issue

```sh
npm install --cache .npm
npm run build --cache .npm
```

This will create a local `.npm` folder

Answer (score 2):

simply try

```
npm rebuild
```

then after completion run your usual command

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue on Windows 8.1:

- Go to your nodejs install (usually C:\Program Files\nodejs)
- Right click node_modules folder and go to properties
- Click the Security tab and advanced
- At the top you will see "Owner: SYSTEM", click change
- Enter the user you want permissions for and click Ok
- Check the box at the bottom of the advanced settings "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" and click ok
- Do whatever npm install/update you need

Answer (score 1):

you could try this, works on ubuntu and mac

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I ran this and worked 100% for me on a mac:   sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Answer (score 1):

use below command while installing packages

```
 sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: If you are interested, see my answer that avoids the need to have `sudo`, for example during a container build. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167840/520567

Answer (score 1):

When trying to install packages globally as root, the process will fail with `EUIDLOOKUP` or `EACCES` or `npm` will mess up your user global packages permissions.

To understand the problem I would suggest reading [this issue](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-baseimage-alpine/issues/47). In short `npm` tries to use the [EUID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27669983/520567) of current process to run installation scripts not as `root` but as the original user running `npm` while at the same time assuming that a user running as root would use `sudo` so [EUID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27669983/520567) will be set.

That's why answer of [@JHM16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63687997/520567) based on using `sudo` should work.

But this is not the case when installing packages inside a container build. In containers `sudo` will be more often than not missing. And build will usually just run as root.

Of course container build can be changed to run these commands as a regular user and build everything as that user. This will not make the build more secure though and could be undesirable in some situations.

So in a container build, here's how you can make `npm` global install work for example with the `yarn` package.

```
# setpriv --ruid 0 --euid 0 npm --unsafe-perm install -g yarn
```

`setpriv` is a small low level utility that should be available or easily installable on any linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was also having the same problem. I was running Ubuntu. Mine problem arises because I'd lost my public key of the Ubuntu. Even updating my system was not happening. It was giving GPG error. In that case, you can regain your key by using this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key in GPG error>
```

After that npm works fine!

Answer (score 0):

John Papa points to the history and reasoning behind this issue and gives [a solid fix](http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/):

John Papa's steps are to:

1. Use brew to install node without npm
2. Update your .bash_profile/.bashrc to let npm and node know where to install and find packages
3. Use brew to update node and npm to update itself

Hope this helps the curious!

Answer (score 0):

@Yves M.'s answer was very similar to my solution.  Here are the commands I used, which were slightly different from his.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
```

Then query for the latest version:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

Then install the newest version:

```
nvm install YOUR_VERSION_HERE
```

example

```
nvm install v5.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What to me seems like the best option is the one suggested in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory), which is to first check where global node_modules are installed by default by running `npm config get prefix`. If you get, like I do on Trusty, `/usr`, you might want to change it to a folder that you can safely own without messing things up the way I did.

To do that, choose or create a new folder in your system. You may want to have it in your home directory or, like me, under `/usr/local` for consistency because I'm also a Mac user (I prefer not to need to look into different places depending on the machine I happen to be in front of). Another good reason to do that is the fact that the `/usr/local` folder is probably already in your PATH (unless you like to mess around with your PATH) but chances are your newly-created folder isn't and you'd need to add it to the PATH yourself on your *.bash-profile* or *.bashrc* file.

Long story short, I changed the default location of the global modules with `npm config set prefix '/usr/local'`, created the folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` (it will be used by npm) and changed permissions for the folders used by npm with the command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

Now you can globally install any module safely. Hope this helps!

Comment: If the user happens to not have these `npm` configs properly set, this will brick their system by recursively setting permissions for the entire OS. This is a really bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Solve it by changing the owner from root to my user-name

`sudo chown -R me:me /home/me/.config/configstore/`

change me with your user-name and group .

Answer (score 0):

I like to use ubuntu groups to achieve this instead of changing owner. Its quite simple.

1. First install nodejs and npm using apt-get

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nodejs npm`
2. Figure out who is logged in i.e username, run following command to see it in terminal

   `whoami`
3. You can see the list of groups you are assigned by using a very simple command, normally the first group is your username itself

   `groups`
4. Run following to allow access to logged in user

   `sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local && sudo chgrp $(whoami) -R /usr/local`
5. Update npm and nodejs

   `npm install -g npm`

You are allset, your user can run npm commands without sudo

You can also refer to this link https://askubuntu.com/a/1115373/687804

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in comments, without any succses, but following command did the magic for me:

```
hash -r
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I utilized and worked.  I tried utilizing `whoami` never worked.

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

then

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/npm`

then

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score -2):

I found that if you only `sudo -s` "it just starts up a shell with root permissions as a one step" and it really works for me. I don't know if it's a good practice or not.

I hope it helps.

Reference: https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/14423/revisions

Answer (score -3):

I set my user account as the owner of the /usr/local directory, so that can just issue normal commands in there.

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

Reference: http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm

Comment: Bad practice to set ownership of system directories to your personal user account.

Answer (score -4):

All the above is not necessary.

The issue I was having was I was using the -g when I was running NPM. I couldn't work out how I wasn't getting a 'npm_module' folder created in my project.

The solution is to run 'NPM init' This creates a 'package.json' and the 'npm_module' folder where all subsequent modules will be loaded into. When running npm DO NOT use -g use -s to update your 'package.json' file.

[Here is a good video explaining](https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-npm-init)

Comment: The video requires a paid subscription.  Can you summarize it and perhaps point to a free resource?  And I assume you mean "npm", not "NPM".

Comment: This answer is not related to the OP's question and contains a link to a subscription-only service.

If you find a solution to a problem that you can't find a StackOverflow question for, it is a good opportunity to create your own question and answer.

Answer (score -7):

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib
```